# Convert two timestamp floats to a readable number of years, months, and days

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, date-arithmetic, python-datetime

I have two timestamps which are stored in float format:

```
tms1 = 1479081600.0
tms2 = 1482105600.0
```

Upon calculating the difference I get

```
tms2 - tms1
3024000.0
```

**How do I go about displaying this time difference of 3024000 into a readable format in days, months or years?** (The answer is 35 days between 14 Nov 2016 to 19 Dec 2016 using an online unix time difference calculator)

Comment: seconds in day `= 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400`, so `3024000.0 / 86400 = 35.0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use (after `import`ing `datetime`)

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3024000).days
```

which is

```
35
```

You should use `timedelta` as this is a time delta - a difference in time, not an absolute time. A full representation can also be obtained by coercing a `timedelta` to a string:

```
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3024000))
```

Gives the output:

```
35 days, 0:00:00
```

Note that you don't need an online calculator for anything - `datetime` comes with batteries included. You could do:

```
import datetime

date_format = "%d %b %Y"

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("14 Nov 2016", date_format)
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("19 Dec 2016", date_format)

print(start_date == datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1479081600))

print(start_date)
print(end_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

diff = end_date - start_date

print(diff)
print(diff.days)
```

which outputs:

```
True
2016-11-14 00:00:00
19/12/2016
35 days, 0:00:00
35
```

Note that `diff` here is identical to the original `timedelta` object, but is dynamically created from `datetime`s rather than statically constructed. I've also demonstrated the fact that you can build a datetime from a timestamp, should you wish, and I've also taken the liberty of demonstrating `strftime` and the like to illustrate the power of datetime. I highly recommend the `datetime` approach over an arithmetic approach as it's a lot more readable and extensible.

This answer is pretty lightweight, which isn't necessarily bad, as often you might not need any more functionality than it provides, but if the `timedelta` between two days is less than 24 hours, it will round down to 0 days, for example. It also can't handle timezones. If you need either of those, see [the legendary Raymond's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899661/how-to-convert-the-days-between-two-timestamp-floats-to-a-readable-format/45900003#45900003)

Answer (score 1):

Just subtracting seconds doesn't help you know whether a day boundary has been crossed, so it is necessary to convert the timestamps to [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects before computing the days.

Add since the timezone can affect what the calendar day is for a UTC timestamp, you may need a [*tzinfo*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) object as well.

Once the calendar dates are known, a little calendar math is needed to compute the difference in years, months, and days:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

def time_diff(start_timestamp, end_timestamp, tz=None):
    """ Return time difference in years, months, and days.

        If *tz* is None, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date 
        and time.  Otherwise, *tz* should be an instance of a *tzinfo* subclass.
    """

    # Determine whether we're going forward or backward in time
    ago = ''
    if end_timestamp < start_timestamp:
        ago = 'ago'
        start_timestamp, end_timestamp = end_timestamp, start_timestamp

    # Compute the calendar dates from the timestamps
    d1  = datetime.fromtimestamp(start_timestamp, tz)
    d2  = datetime.fromtimestamp(end_timestamp, tz)

    # Advance d1 day-by-day until the day is at or above d2.day
    days = 0
    while d2.day < d1.day:
        days += 1
        d1 += timedelta(days=1)

    # Now compute the day difference
    days += d2.day - d1.day

    # Compute the totals months difference and express in years and months
    total_months = (d2.year * 12 + d2.month) - (d1.year * 12 + d1.month)
    years, months = divmod(total_months, 12)

    # format the output
    plural = lambda n: '' if n == 1 else 's'
    return '%d year%s, %d month%s, and %d day%s %s' % (
        years, plural(years), months, plural(months), days, plural(days), ago)
```

Here is an example of how to use the function:

```
from datetime import tzinfo

class GMT1(tzinfo):
    # Example tzinfo subclass taken from the Python docs
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=1)
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)
    def tzname(self,dt):
        return "Europe/Prague"

print(time_diff(1479081600.0, 1482105600.0, tz=GMT1()))
```

This outputs:

```
0 years, 1 month, and 5 days
```